# Изучаю HttpClient. Есть вопросы

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Ковыряю HttpClient. По офиц документации.

```cs
static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

static async Task GetDataTask(Uri url)
{

  try   
  {
 //как "положить" сюда urlArg
     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
     response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
     string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

     Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
  }  
  catch(HttpRequestException e)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");  
     Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ",e.Message);
  }
}
```

Далее основная часть:

```cs
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string ResievedData;
            Uri urlArg = new Uri("https://MojSait.my");
             GetDataTask(urlArg).Start();

        }
```

**1.** Как "передать" урлю urlArg для скачивания в Task?

**2.** Чем принципиально отличается Task от того, чтобы сделать обычный метод и также вызвать его асинхронно!?

**3.** И почему в примере используется static ..Main() просто потому что пример для консольного приложения? Зачем static? Просто из соображений минимализма?

Comment: `static async Task Main()` - это стартовая точка приложения, которая в [C# 7.1](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1#async-main) начала поддерживать асинхронность и "таски". Другими словами у вас сейчас две стартовые точки)) Сделайте отдельный метод, который возвращает `Task<string>` и делайте `await client.GetStringAsync(uri);`. Тогда уже можете делать `ResievedData = await SomeMethod();`.

Comment: Весело, но оно и без этого работало. Видимо, первый Main как делегат компилятором воспринимался. Подправил код.

Comment: Ну подправили, и? Чего не понятно сейчас? Я вроде сказал, что ваш метод должен вернуть значение, а значит он должен быть не `Task`, а `Task<string>` и нужное он должен вернуть через `return`. А `static void Main(string[] args)` уж тогда переписывайте в асинхронный, раз у вас вызов "таски" идет и в нем вызывайте задачу (`var result = await GetDataTask();`).

Comment: string s1=t.Result; ?  Еще не привык к шарпу... Даже не подумал, что Task может что-то возвращать.

Comment: Почитайте про `async/await` - это некие асинхронные операции, которые позволяют выполнить задачу в фоне, не тормозя основной поток (UI), там принято использовать `Task` - это задача, которую можно дождаться, она по сути как метод - может вернуть некое значение, либо просто выполниться и все. Когда вы пишете `async MyTask()`, то приложение сделает нечто в фоне и после продолжен выполнение основного кода. Если у вас `Task<T>`, то на выходе (после выполнения) у вас будет `T`, то есть объект, который вы возвращаете.

Comment: Если вы пишете `t.Result;`, то вы получаете из задачи результат после выполнения, но операция делается синхронно, то есть во время ее выполнения ваше приложение скорей всего зависнет.

Comment: Это как раз все понятно. Причём Task - Это задача, а не новый поток, эту разницу тоже понял. Просто еще не пользовался всем этим... Как делать красивую синхронизацию с основным кодом[делать свои event или нет], как создавать очередь для отправки пакетов и т.д... Почитаю.

Comment: А передать параметр как?

Comment: Вы вопрос до бесконечности будете редактировать? Во первых вы задаете Вопрос", а не "ВопроСЫ", на SO так принято, придерживайтесь этому правилу! Во вторых, на SO нехорошо менять суть вопроса, вы сейчас редактированием своих вопросов это делаете. Ну ок, 1. Вы знаете как работают методы в C#? `Task` не отличается от метода почти не чем, передавайте ваш `Uri` через аргумент (`GetDataTask(Uri uri)`). 2. Вопрос совершенно не относится к `HttpClient`. Отличие у них в том, что асинхронные методы (void) вы не можете дождаться, а `Task` можете. 3. На этот вопрос я уже давал ответ первым комментарием.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что не работает Task.Run(GetDataTask(url_arg));  Я изучаю материал... вопросов всегда много. Самые ёмкие базовые понятия в сложной теме, хотелось бы правильно всё усвоить

Comment: Я не вижу, что вы здесь что либо принимаете `static async Task GetDataTask()`. По поводу "емких базовых понятий" - `HttpClient` - это не базовое понятие, вам надо понять что такое методы, классы, какой синтаксис у языка, как все работает и уже потом приступать к пониманию тех или иных возможностей языка.

Comment: `await client.GetAsync(urlArg);` - мне вас за ручку что ли вести?

Comment: Там компилятор ругается Аргумент 1: не удается преобразовать из "System.Threading.Tasks.Task" в "System.Action" на var t = Task.Run(GetDataTask(urlArg));

Comment: Потому что все, что у вас в `Main` - это непонятная каша. `Task.Run(GetDataTask(urlArg));` - Вы делаете `Task`, в который хотите засунуть `Task`. `t.Wait();` - тоже не пойми зачем вы используете. Я уже несколько раз вам сказал, как должно быть.

Comment: Спасибо! Task - довольно базовая штука! Видите благодаря вам уже начинаю осваивать. Код исправил. А он казался странным не зря!